# Can the HS-Omega-3 Index be calculated from EPA and DHA?

Tags: blood-tests, test-results, omega-3

I want to test my levels of Omega 3s, and I'm curious if it makes sense to test both the HS-Omega-3 Index and the EPA (Eicosapentaenoic Acid) & DHA (Docosahexaenoic Acid), or just the latter?

According to this [study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341296482_Omega-3_index_in_201819), the Omega 3 index is the "percentage of EPA plus DHA in erythrocytes". Thus it seems to me that the answer should be if I test only for EPA and DHA, I would implicitly get the HS-Omega-3 Index result, I could calculate it myself. Is that so?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. This question borders on asking for medical advice which is off-topic. But, it is not strictly asking for medical advice and is on topic for this site in my view. Just a heads up to be careful with your questions that you don't get flagged for asking advice which might be medical advice specific to you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Chris, I will keep that in mind for the future. I think this question is fairly objective: given two inputs (EPA and DHA), can one get an output (HS-Omega-3)?